# Running mpi4py with nohup. mpiexec noticed that process rank 6 with PID 70581 on node ip-x-xx-xx-xxxx exited on signal 1 (Hangup)

Tags: python, parallel-processing, mpi, nohup

I was trying to run a python script which is modified to perform operations in multiple cores. I tried to run the same operation using nohup and it was working fine but when I tried to run it on a larger sample I got the following error. mpiexec noticed that process rank 6 with PID 70581 on node ip-xx-x-x-xxx exited on signal 1 (Hangup). 
Any idea about why it is happening and how to rectify it. Also it would be great if somebody can suggest a better way to run a python script in multiple cores.

For example I have a script abc.py

```
a=[1,2,3,4]
result=[]

def foo(x,y):
    #do some maths
    score_pair=#some more maths depending on x and y
    return score_pair

if __name__=='__main__':
    for x in a:
        for y in a:
            score_pair=foo(x,y)
            result.append([x,y,score_pair])
    #save result in pickle
```

I modified the for loop using mpi4py such that the script could utilise the multiple cores available on the computer. I was running the python script using

```
 nohup mpiexec -n 16 python abc.py > nohupfile.out &
```

The code works well as long as the size of a is small (i.e. the execution time is small). If I increase the size of a, the process hangup giving the above mentioned error. 
Any idea how to rectify this? If there is some other way to parallelize the script?

Comment: Please be more specific on how you exactly execute the application.  Can you reproduce that with a [mcve].

Comment: @Zulan: Please see the edited question.

Comment: I can't really tell why the error occurs, but you aren't even using MPI in your script. Things you can try: [GNU parallel](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/) instead of MPI, if you don't use communication. [GNU screen](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/screen.html) instead of nohup.

Comment: @Zulan: I have used it in my original code. This is just an illustration for what I want to do.